# Can Hibernate map NULL to the not-a-number float?

Tags: java, hibernate, floating-point

Here is my Hibernate mapping of a particular column:

`<property name="maxRating" not-null="false" column="max_rating"/>`

In the database (Postgres), the column is `max_rating double precision`, i.e. it is nullable in the table.  The Java class being mapped has a member `private float maxRating`.

Without changing the table definition or the class, is there a way to get Hibernate to map a `NULL` value in this column to `Float.NaN` in the instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create a user type:

```
package my.pkg.type;

public class NullNanFloatType implements UserType {

    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{Types.FLOAT};
    }

    public Class returnedClass() {
        return Float.class;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return ( x == y ) || ( x != null && x.equals( y ) );
    }

    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        float value = rs.getFloat(names[0]);
        if (rs.wasNull()) {
            value = Float.NaN;
        }
        return new Float(value);
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement ps, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null || Float.isNaN(((Float)value).floatValue())) {
            ps.setNull(index, Types.FLOAT);
        } else {
            ps.setFloat(index, ((Float)value).floatValue());
        }
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        //returning value should be OK since floats are immutable
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
}
```

and then you should be able to set the property mapping to

```
<property name="maxRating" 
          not-null="false" 
          column="max_rating" 
          type="my.pkg.type.NullNanFloatType" />
```

Comment: Would this not require my mapped class to change its property type from `float` to `java.lang.Float`, violating the constraints of the question?  If so, then it seems that `UserType` is not a viable solution, as its `nullSafeGet` and `nullSafeSet` methods use `Object` and therefore forbid primitives.

Comment: That is not a problem, as Hibernate internally uses the wrapper classes to represent primitives.

Comment: I've tried this solution with hibernate 3.6.1 and did not encounter any problems.

Comment: I see, Hibernate has specific logic for the primitives.  I'll give this a shot.